# Unable to biblatex.sty on CentOS 7

Tags: biblatex, centos

On CentOS 7, when I want to use BibLaTeX in a document, pdflatex returns the following error:

> Latex Error: File 'biblatex.sty' not found.

I have installed the packages texlive-bibtex.noarch, texlive-bibtex-bin.x86_64.

I tried to copy `biblatex.sty` from an Ubuntu system to CentOS on the folder */usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/* but the problem still persists.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\citetitle{misc1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what have you installed on your CenOS 7 (there are at least two ways to install TeXLive, so details matter). Note that searcing the HD is slow so just copying in `biblatex.sty` will not work without updating the filename database. Again details matter. My guess: you installed TeXLive from CentOS. As with other Linux dists, CentOS has split TeXLive into smaller CentOS packages, abd you have only installed a subset of these and are missing the one the provides `biblatex.sty`.

Comment: I have installed a lot of packages to include sty files.
texlive-lastpage to have lastpage.sty,
texlive-titlesec to have titlesec.sty,
But I can't find the package for the biblatex.sty.

Comment: If you're installing using the CentOS package manager, then minimally you need to install `texlive-biblatex` , `texlive-biblatex-ieee` and `texlive-biber` if those exist for CentOS. You may find it preferable to use the TeXLive installer rather than using the distro packages. See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: Alan, the trouble don't comes with Debian or Ubuntu. On centOs 7, the package texlive-biber don't exists. Thanks

Comment: So I guess then installing a vanilla TeXLive instead is the way to go. This is a perpetual problem with linux distros trying to distribute TeXLive...

Comment: The one containing biber might simply be called `biber`. This is why on Ubuntu I tend to recommend users use the `apt-file` tool to tell them which Ubuntu package provides a certain file. I'm sure something similar exists on CentOS. On Ubuntu `apt-file search biblatex.sty` gives me `texlive-bibtex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty` meaning I'd need to installa `texlive-bibtex-extra`.

Comment: If you have enough space on your HD, then there also ought to be a `texlive-full` or `texlive-all` meta package that installs everything TeXLive related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS 7, biblatex.sty is not available.
The command `yum provides "*biblatex.sty"` return no results.
I decide to use the **natbib** which is available and functionnal.

Thanks